# How to set internet proxy with authentication in .bat file?

Tags: batch-file, proxy, settings

I bought private proxy that needs authentication.
I built a batch file and add the following this script but didn't work:

```
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyEnable /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyServer /t REG_SZ /d http://username:password@IP Address:PORT /f
```

Thanks in advance